# CSS positioning not working on Chrome

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, position

I have a Wordpress site and I wanted to display two vertical banners outside of the main container. I am using this css and it works on Firefoxs and IE. On Chrome however only the left one is shown. Any ideas?

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1100px){
    div.side-image-left {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 98;
        left: -840px;
        top: -24px;
    }

    div.side-image-right {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 99;
        left: 342px;
        top: -24px;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you only see the right one since the left one has -840px for position

Comment: why using `media-queries` ? apart from that from *CSS* only we can;t help you except the `position` issue, consider creating [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Without the positioning context the code is not much use. A demo is probably required.

Comment: the html <div> 's are called in the sidemenu within a widget. the -840px works in all browsers! The side-image-right works only in IE and Firefox, not chrome....

Comment: As specified, the code we have isn't enough to demonstrate the issue. A demo is required.

Comment: www.ergasianews.gr is the live site.

As stated before, banners are displayed correctly on IE and FF, on Chrome only one of the two is displayed correctly.

Comment: I see the problem, but the site is a bit large for us to debug. Besides, if you're currently working on it, it's a moving target: any answer based on it may be outdated as soon as it's posted. So please create a smaller (in terms of source code) version; as small as possible while still demonstrating the issue. Also, the two sidebars, in Mozilla the left one is sticky while the right one is static, is that by design?

Comment: yes that's the way it's supposed to be. Left one sticky, right one static. Working on FF & IE, not showing on Chrome. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Declaring a width seems to fix the issue at least for me `div.side-image-right { width: 120px; }` for example

Comment: Yes! @lordthorzonus solution worked. Right banner now displays correctly on Chrome too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can try floating the image not positioning. Now, as I have seen you used absolute positioning, so in this approach you also won't get always get the banners when scrolling down.

```
.side-left-image{
float:left; }

.side-right-image{
float: right; }
```

but z-index won't work!